# How can I get Chrome GPU information through scripts or any other means?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, gpu

I want to run diagnostics of Chrome GPU, before loading a new tab which can view 3D data. I want to run a diagnostics to check if some GPU options are turned on, before loading the new tab.

How can I get Chrome GPU information through scripts or any other means?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking.

You can get the GPU info by using the [`WEBGL_debug_renderer_info`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_debug_renderer_info) extension.

```js
function getGPUInfo() {
  const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl");
  const ext = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_debug_renderer_info');
  return ext ? {
    vendor: gl.getParameter(ext.UNMASKED_VENDOR_WEBGL),
    renderer: gl.getParameter(ext.UNMASKED_RENDERER_WEBGL),
  } : { 
    vendor: "unknown",
    renderer: "unknown",
  };
}

console.log(getGPUInfo());
```

Comment: Actually i need all the information available in chrome://gpu. Whether i can get those information without manually going and checking chrome://gpu page?

Comment: Sorry, no, not from a webpage you can not get that info. Even `WEBGL_debug_renderer_info` is/was controversial. [See panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/)